# How to inject into new SomeObject()

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I got a class like the following:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private SomeClass someclass;

    //...
}
```

If I create this class by `new MyClass()` then `someClass` is `null`. If I inject `MyClass` it is not. But I need the construction with new here. I know I could pass someClass to MyClass via constructor, but I don't want this. What other possibilities do I have here?

Comment: @Downvoters: Why down-vote? Please tell me what I should do to get your approval. I will fix the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a pretty nice solution. The trick is to inject ´MyClass´ in the following way:

```
@Inject
private Instance<MyClass> myClass;
```

Then you can construct the bean via

```
myClass.get();
```

This encapsulates the usage of the beanManager.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using CDI or something similar. For injection to work in that case the framework has to "see" the need to inject something (and where to inject that). That's generally done by creating `MyClass` instances by using the framework as well but there might also be a way to trigger injection manually.

In terms of CDI it would be something like this:

```
BeanManager bm = ...; //lookup or let it inject        
Bean<MyClass> bean = (Bean<MyClass>)bm.getBeans( MyClass.class ).iterator().next();    
CreationalContext<T> ctx= bm.createCreationalContext( bean );    
MyClass instance = bm.getReference( bean, MyClass.class, ctx);
```

Comment: That doesn't look too much 'clean-code' to me. Isn't there a 'nicer' solution? Something like a best practice?

Comment: @Chris311 you could as well let CDI inject an instance of `MyClass` to where you need it. In case you don't have injection there (because the target itself is not managed by CDI) you'll have to use code similar to the above (maybe wrapped in a method). In fact, you need some integration between your non-managed and managed objects so you need some "boilerplate" looking code.